# Non-trivial faces of the closed convex hull of a non-convex closed set with connected complement

Tags: functional-analysis, convex-analysis, hilbert-spaces, convex-hulls

I'm trying to prove or disprove a problem, but I'm struggling to make headway. Any help is appreciated.

> Suppose $X$ is a Hilbert Space, and $C \subseteq X$ is closed, bounded, non-convex, and $X \setminus C$ is connected. Does the boundary of $\operatorname{conv} C$ necessarily contain a line segment?

The following are my thoughts on the problem:

The connectedness and openness of the complement gives us an open subset of the boundary of $\operatorname{conv} C$ that doesn't intersect $C$. The Bishop-Phelps theorem tells us that support points are dense in the boundary of convex sets, so there must exist support points of $\overline{\operatorname{conv}} C$ that aren't contained in $C$.

If we choose one such point, by translation, we can say it is $0$ without loss of generality. If this point is not extreme in $\overline{\operatorname{conv}} C$, then we are done. However, such points can be extreme (e.g. take $C$ to be the standard orthonormal basis in $l^2$, in which case $0$ is such a point).

I decided to look at the tangent cone of $\overline{\operatorname{conv}} C$ from the point $0$. I then picked a support point $x$ of this cone, other than $0$, but close enough that we could guarantee that it would not be in $C$. The supporting hyperplane must support the set $\overline{\operatorname{conv}} C$ at $0$. I'm hoping to show that $x \in \overline{\operatorname{conv}} C$.

This is where I get stuck. If the functional that supports at $x$ achieves its maximum on $C$, then I get to the result, but this may not be the case.

Again, any help is appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Comment: @Desire: Ah yes, that's right. Boundedness is necessary. I'll edit to include that.

Comment: You said : "The connectedness and openness of the complement gives us an open subset of the boundary of  $\bar{\text{conv}(C)} $ that doesn't intersect $C.$ " ?!

what if $C$ just contains two points.?

Comment: @Redshoes Then $\overline{\operatorname{conv}}C$ is a line segment. The open line segment is open in the boundary (in the subspace topology), and doesn't intersect $C$.

Comment: OK .. I misunderstood it.

Comment: Does non-trivial face just mean non-empty and dimension at least 1?

Comment: @Dap Yes, but I'd phrase it slightly differently: non-empty, and not a singleton. It's probably good if the face is closed too.

Comment: Actually, now that I think about it, the question is a little bit troubled. Firstly, I obviously needed to specify a proper face, as the entire convex hull would trivially suffice. But then @Redshoes' example poses a problem too because there are no proper non-trivial faces. I think at least, we would need to assume that the affine hull of the convex set is at least one dimension (possibly infinite). Suddenly, the posed problem seems less natural...

Comment: @TheoBendit I thought from the beginning you meant non empty and not a singleton; that is, prove that the boundary contains a segment. This is an interesting and I think non trivial question (and also natural to me). The example by Red shoes satisfies this, so it's ok

Comment: Seems like Corollary 1 in https://wydawnictwa.ptm.org.pl/index.php/commentationes-mathematicae/article/download/5806/5347 is the result you are looking for.

Comment: @daw I don't think I can use this. In order to give me local compactness with respect to the topology, I'll need to use the weak topology. But then, the conclusion will only give me that the extreme point lies in the weak closure of $C$, which will be (in general) larger than $C$, as $C$ is only assumed to be norm-closed.

Comment: Missed that :( What is your intuition: Is the result true or not?

Comment: @daw I feel about 70% sure it's true, for what it's worth. A counterexample would be quite the thing to behold!